# How do I iterate over each word separated by spaces?

Tags: c, string, ansi-c

I'm looking for a way to iterate over each word within a string gathered from the `getchar()` function in C. I can't use pointers. Each word in the sentence will have something done to it but should not be affected by the other words and I need a way to access the letters, such as even if I'm at the third word, `buffer[k]` if `k = 0` would give the first letter of the third word.

```
void read_line (char buffer[])
{
    char character;
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 32; ++i)
    {
        character = getchar ();
        buffer[i] = character;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why no pointers? They're a pretty standard feature of C :-)

Comment: What do you think `buffer` is in this scenario (hint; it's not an array)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you would use strchr to find a space in the string, but since you can't use pointers:

```
void read_line (char buffer[]) 
{ 
    char character; 
    int i = 0; 

    for (i = 0; i < 32; ++i) 
    { 
        character = getchar (); 

        if (character == '\n')
            break;

        buffer[i] = character; 
    } 

    i = 0;

    while (buffer[i] != '\n')
    {
        for (; buffer[i] != ' '; ++i)
            // each iteration of this loop will be on the same word

        ++i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of hard without pointers (you're passing arrays around, those are pointers, too). But you can probably do without allocating memory at all. Take a look at [strtok](http://www.elook.org/programming/c/strtok.html).

Clarification:

As @EdS pointed out in the comments below, arrays and pointers are *not* the same thing. However, they are *pretty much* the same thing under many circumstances. Passing an array to a function and passing a pointer to a function is almost always the same thing - practically.

So, remember pointers and arrays are not the same, and that you should learn the difference, but don't worry about it just yet.

Comment: *"you're passing arrays around, those are pointers, too"* - I know what you mean by that, but it is probably a really bad thing to say to an obvious beginner.  Arrays are *not* pointers, at all ever, though they do degrade to pointers in many scenarios (such as this one).

Comment: @EdS. But you alluded to the buffer being a pointer in the comment on the question. Also Arrays are a reference to the start of a block of memory that is allocated to be the length of the array. This sounds a lot like a pointer to me.

Comment: @Ben: I think you missed the point of my comment.  I understand what zmbq was getting at with that statement (I think I do anyway) because I understand arrays, pointers, and when arrays degrade to pointers.  However, confusing arrays with pointers is a huge issue beginners run into and comments which, when taken literally, say "arrays and pointers are the same thing" are wrong and very misleading.

Answer (score 1):

You want to read a written string line and count words, is this right?

First, read the string with:

```
char* str = gets(NULL);
int i = 0;
char* tok = strtok(str," ");
while(tok != NULL) {
    i++;
    tok = strtok(NULL, " ");
}
```

You count all words, separated by a space.